How to show hidden columns of a table in "phpoffice/phpword"?
In laravel 10 app using "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2" I need to write with several columns with long width
and resulting table in docx file looks not goood, as passing data with 6 columns :
    $tableColumns = [
        ['column_id' => 'doc_code', 'title' => 'Document code', 'width' => 1500, 'align' => 'left'],
        ['column_id' => 'doc_title', 'title' => 'Document title', 'width' => 5000],
        ['column_id' => 'doc_type', 'title' => 'Type', 'width' => 2000],
        ['column_id' => 'doc_status', 'title' => 'Status', 'width' => 2000],
        ['column_id' => 'department_name', 'title' => 'Department', 'width' => 3000],
        ['column_id' => 'applied_from', 'title' => 'applied_from', 'width' => 1500],
    ];
    $this->addTableWithData( // table with employee docs
        dataArray: $docsData,
        columnsArray: $tableColumns,
        titleWordTextLineEnum: 'HeaderText'
    );

actually I see only 4 columns : 1st and 6th columns are not visible
Reading here https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#table I did not find if this table hase any horizontal scrolling

If there a way somehow show 6 columns with big width ?
In my code above I show columns with width. Which is biggest summary of all columns ?

ATTEMPT TO FIX :
method addTableWithData in my post that is my function which draws table with given data. It had code :
protected function addTableWithData(array $dataArray, array $columnsArray, string $titleWordTextLineEnum, string $tableHeader= ''): void
{
    //        \Log::info(QuizzesInitFacade::varDump($dataArray, ' -1 addTableWithData $dataArray::'));
    $section = $this->phpWord->addSection(['marginTop' => 50, 'marginLeft' => 50, 'marginRight' => 50,
                                           'marginBottom' => 50, 'breakType' => 'continuous']);
    $fontStyle = $this->setFontStyleByWordTextLineEnum($titleWordTextLineEnum);
    if($tableHeader) {
        $textElement = $section->addText('Answers');
        $textElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);
    }

    $rows = count($dataArray);
    $cols = count($columnsArray);

    $table = $section->addTable($this->getTableStyle());
    $table->addRow();
    for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
        $table->addCell($columnsArray[$col]['width'])->addText(Str::headline($columnsArray[$col]['title']), $this->getTableHeaderLineStyle(), array('align' => 'center'));
    }

    for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
        $table->addRow();
        for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
            $cellValue = '';
            if(isset($dataArray[$row][$columnsArray[$col]['column_id']])) {
                $columnId = $columnsArray[$col]['column_id'];
                $val = $dataArray[$row][$columnId] ?? '';
                $cellValue = $this->getTableCellValue($val, $columnId, $row, $col);
            }
            $cellAlign = 'left';
            if(!empty($columnsArray[$col]['align'])) {
                $cellAlign = $columnsArray[$col]['align'];
            }
            $table->addCell($columnsArray[$col]['width'])->addText($cellValue, $this->getTableContentRowLineStyle(), array('align' => $cellAlign)) ;
        }
    }
}

I try to modify it like in @Omair tahir sample as :
protected function addTableWithData(array $dataArray, array $columnsArray, string $titleWordTextLineEnum, string $tableHeader= ''): void
{
    $section = $this->phpWord->addSection(['marginTop' => 600, 'marginLeft' => 600, 'marginRight' => 600,
         'marginBottom' => 600, 'breakType' => 'continuous']); // I tried to set margin props bigger -no effect


    // $section has no any getSettings function :
    // dd($section->getSettings()); // If to uncomment this line it shows "Null" - so error Call to a member function setMarginLeft() on null on next line
    $section->getSettings()->setMarginLeft(-600);

It seems to me that I create $section in the same way ... Also looking at
https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/stable/general.html?highlight=getSettings#magnification-setting

I did not any examples that getSettings method in $section object...
?
